# Update the google maps marker without rebuilding the map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the google maps api like this:

```
this.init_map = function(lat, lng){
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  zoom: 17,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  map: map,
  title:"I'm Here!"
});
}
```

This takes lat and lng, and draws the map just fine, but when new lat & lng variables get pushed into this function over a websocket the page doesn't reload, but the map gets re drawn with the marker in the new lat & lng position.

I want to update the marker on the map without redrawing the map.

Comment: you should not ask two questions in one

Comment: hint for your second question: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds

Comment: if you use rails, consider using gmaps4rails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var map = null;
var markers = [];

this.init_map = function(){
var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
 zoom: 17,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
}

this.addMarker = function(lat, lng, id){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map,
    title:"I'm Here!"
  });
  markers.push({ id: id, markerObject: marker});
}

this.updateMarkerCoordinates(lat, lng, id){
  //I let you loop the markers array, compare ids and retrieve the marker
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
}
```

Comment: I still couldn't quite figure it out, but it's more a problem of how I'm getting the data into the JS but yes, I think you answered it. Thanks

Comment: This is just adds a marker. How do you tell the map to redraw wen you update an existing marker?